# Barcode Reader using scandit sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, barcode-scanner

I am using the Scandit SDK's barcode scanner. I followed all the instructions, ran the demo "Project" supplied by "Scandit", but it crashed when clicking on any button. Is this an iOS related problem?

I made sure to include the "APP Key" provided by "Scandit". Please help.

Comment: what does the crash backtrace look like?  if you run the project with the Xcode debugger, does it crash on a certain line?

Answer (score 2):

This is Christian from the Scandit support team.

The problem you describe is most likely a problem with the app key integration.

Can you double-check that you added the app key correctly for our iOS barcode scanner to your xcode project?

If you continue to have problems, feel free to also send us an email at Scandit support.

Comment: hi Christian could you please take a look at my problem and see if you could give me some advice? thanks! "Scandit Barcode Scanner iOS Crash"

Answer (score 0):

Error:
**wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
Scandit SDK activation failed (Error 403). Make sure your app key is valid and check your account for available device activations.**
Ideas ?

UPDATE: Obvious it's a problem with the app key, but i can;t tell what is. I used the app key from https://ssl.scandit.com/account/apps .